# How to do the equivalent of Gen.filter in a gen CE

Tags: f#, fscheck

FsCheck offers the `Gen.filter` / `Gen.where` functions. Example:

```ml
type Status = Pending | Activated | Deactivated
type Item = { Id: int; Status: Status }

let nonPendingItemGen =
    Arb.generate
    |> Gen.filter (fun item -> item.Id > 0 && item.Status <> Pending }
```

Is it possible to refactor this code to use `gen` computation expression with the "filter" inside?

- A quick attempt using an `if` statement failed because of the type discrepancies between the `if` and the `else` branches.
- I found a solution by generating a sequence and then filter this sequence but I find it less elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by generating a valid ID and status within the computation expression and then constructing the item from those values. Instead of thinking about what values you *don't* want, think about the values you *do* want and generate them:

```ml
let nonPendingItemGen =
    gen {
        let! id = Arb.generate<PositiveInt>
        let! status = Gen.elements [ Activated; Deactivated ]
        return { Id = id.Get; Status = status }
    }
```

This approach is more efficient in general, because you don't waste time generating (and then rejecting) invalid items.

Note that I've used FsCheck's built-in `PositiveInt` type. Alternatively, you could generate a positive integer directly via:

```ml
Gen.choose (1, Int32.MaxValue)
```